# Protect against a DoS attack without a CAPTCHA

Tags: asp.net, jquery, captcha, denial-of-service

I'd love to know a good way to protect against DoS attacks on my email and contact forms.

I have a "Share with a Friend" function which opens up a form I've created, but I'd rather not put in a CAPTCHA.

I've seen a jQuery + PHP solution here: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Safer_Contact_Forms_Without_CAPTCHAs#PHP_File

It looks like a good solution, I'd just like some help translating the PHP into C#. I'm guessing an ASHX file would be best to use.

If there are also other (better?) solutions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: I think maybe you are confused as to what a DoS attack is? A CAPTCHA only helps against automated bots attempting to use a system. A DoS attempt is usually at the packet level and makes no attempt to actually use the system at hand.

Comment: How about a Captcha that has it's src property set to the IP address of the attacker?  Everytime he makes a request to your page, you can make one right back at him. :)

Comment: @George, if you already know it's an 'attacker' you should just block them. An attacker is unlikely to make use of your response.

Comment: Unlike an attacker would go so far as to request an IMG url anyways. Those are generally trivial to serve up. Far better to hit a PHP page repeatedly (especially if it's a "complicated" one), so as to maximize the hit on database/server resources.

Comment: I was actually trying to stop SPAM from hitting the mailbox. What was happening is People would use the "tell a friend" to spam others and we'd get the denied emails back to our box.

Answer (score 6):

For the record, a captcha won't help against a DOS attack.
The attacking pc's would just be calling your site repeatedly, rendering it unresponsive, without caring about what you return as response (with or without captcha).
A capctha will help you against other kind of attacks such as bots and automatic subscriptions.

In case you are using a hosting provider, they should normally protect you form DOS attacks.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid being used as a spam redirector. The "Email a Friend" function of the site was being used as a mass emailer... we were getting thousands of denied email requests.

Answer (score 1):

Make a form with no action parameter. Add the parameter using JavaScript.

Comment: That's pretty neat! What happens if the user's browser has JS disabled?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using javascript based solution, since this can hurt usability.

Comment: People who are savvy enough to figure out how to turn off JavaScript usually use two browsers, on with and one without. Then things don't work on a site, they just swap browsers.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: I recommend turning off javascript... see how many sites function.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.projecthoneypot.org/

Answer (score 1):

[mollom](http://mollom.com/) - is easy to work with and much smarter than just captcha. I found that it works really well, and is very easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could block or re-direct requests if they occur too quickly. It would have to be coded into your webserver to work well, though, unless you want to have a master file-serving script like `http://www.example.com/gimmeh.py?file=background.png`.